# Get details of object from unrelated element in angular

Tags: html, angular

I am following the basic 'Tour of Heros' tutorial and sort of adding my own needed elements as I go (bootstrap, ng-bootstrap etc) and I want to grab the 'selected hero' from hero details when I reach it and put the name of the hero in a navbar component.

Like so, but obviously with a way to access the selected hero

```
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="nav-link" routerLink="/detail" routerLinkActive="active">{{selectedHero.name}}</div>
        </li>
      </div>
```

My navbar is called by app.component.html above the routing outlet

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have already looked up several questions related to this sort of thing but havnt really found anything made sense or worked when I tried it (I am assuming I am not doing them correctly or a similar issue)
I am new to angular and I feel like this sort of access is something I should know asap

I have seen 'emitters' and 'parent-child relationship' etc but not sure how to go about that with my navbar and the selected hero. The tutorial im following (that has all the code that im working with) is: https://angular.io/tutorial

**Edit** Ive also considered just calling the 'navbar' component within every other main component (as in, within 'hero-detail.component.html' above the actual information) but I think that goes against standards/repeating code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hero details component and the navbar component have no relationship, so to share data between them you simply need to create a shared service between them that can pass data back and forth like this:

**selected-hero.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class SelectedHeroService {
selectedHero = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Default Name Of Hero To Be Shown Goes Here');
selectedHeroObservable = this.selectedHero.asObservable();

changeSelectedHero(newHero:string):void{
this.selectedHero.next(newHero)
  }
}
```

and then in your navbar component, you can read the selected hero like this:

**navbar.component.ts**

```
constructor(private sh: SelectedHeroService ) {
    this.sh.selectedHeroObservable 
       .subscribe((hero) => {
              //add your logic here!! for now I'm just gonna console log the selected hero
              console.log(hero);
          });
    }
```

To set a new hero in you heroes details component you call this method:

**hero-details.component.ts**

```
changeSelectedHero(){
this.sh.changeSelectedHero('My New Selected Hero');
}
```

and don't forget to add the service in the provides arrays and both of the components in the declarations array of the same module so you don't get any errors. Also, don't forget to unsubscribe from the `selectedHeroObservable` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Would it be a better practice to follow this for my situation and situations like mine in the future (passing information from unrelated items) or use the other answer for a more 'global' system of messaging or is it up to me? what is the industry standard for these sorts of things if I may ask

Comment: the other answer is similar but it uses a normal subject but I wanted to use a BehaviorSubject as it lets you set a default value so your navbar could show something when the page load which I guess better than a blank space. also, I wanted to show you how to fully implement the code in your component rather than just giving you the service code only.

Comment: Thanks for the responce, can I nest this service in the folder of navbar so Its all well placed or are such services usually in their own 'service' folder and/or just in the app root folder, I am very new to angular and want to ensure my practices are proper for the industry :)

Comment: create a new typescript file wherever you want you could create for example a folder called services in the root and place it there to keep your project structure clean. and then paste the code I gave you and then go to your app.module.ts and import it and add it the providers array.

Comment: I got the error 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined' when trying to set the name, image of where i am setting name here: https://i.imgur.com/SMMEwfe.png

Comment: Nevermind, I made a method called 'onSelectedHero' in my hero-detail and just called the item in the HTML like so; <div *ngIf="hero; then changeSelectedHero(hero.name)"> just not used to dealing with logic within HTML as angular intends, thanks so much for the super handy code

Answer (score 1):

Component interaction in Angular could be simplified as i use angular at least to three ways: @ViewChild, EventEmitter (Output) or Input.

Viewchild is as it sound when you have a child component and you could set variable declaration (#) in the template to directly have access to methods on the child component.

Eventemitter is used in the child component when you want to notify the parent.

Input is used to set a property in a child.

A part from these three ways to communicate within components there is also services. I use this aproach when the components are too far from each other.

And to answer your question i would go with the service aproach. Have a look at subjects. Check out this plunker!!

```
export class MessageService {
private subject = new Subject<any>();

sendMessage(message: string) {
    this.subject.next({ text: message });
}

clearMessage() {
    this.subject.next();
}

getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FHIPt1?p=preview

Comment: This seems pretty clear from the plnkr you gave but I was just wondering why your folder is called '_service' and why is it just index.ts, instead of say service.componenet.ts or whatever, is it just ur personal naming convention or some other reaosn?